# When do we need to pip install future

Tags: python, future

As per the documentation the module `future` provides `__future__` imports which can make the code Python2 & 3 compatible.

https://pypi.org/project/future/

But, doesn't the Python 2.7 already include `__future__` by default.?

My question is, when exactly would we need to do `pip install future`.?

The question might link to the difference between `future` and `__future__`.

Comment: @selcuk, Thanks for linking the question. I am still finding it difficult to understand the exact difference between `future` and `__future__`. Can you please help me understand a little about the exact difference? Thanks,

Comment: Not sure what part you find confusing. From the linked answer: `The __future__ module is built-in to Python, [...] python-future is a third-party module, one of several to provide compatibility features.`